# Export/Copy Image's Hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Excel has images with hyperlink. I want to copy the hyperlinks of these images. The number of pictures is too many. The order doesn't matter.

I selected and copied all the images with F5>Object. I only looked for text or hyperlinks in the paste options, but unfortunately there are none. I tried pasting it into Notepad, it didn't work.

Comment: try save as 'html' > Open it in browser > r-click > view-source . Does it appear there?